# What does [input] mean in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I saw this in saample source code project.

```
    [Input]
    public int Length { get; set; }
```

It was defined in a class:

```
    namespace PowerLanguage.Strategy
    {
        public class MovAvg_Cross_SE : SignalObject
        {
   ....
```

What does the [input] mean?

Comment: Sounds like a custom `Attribute`.  (I don't see this class in any of the core framework classes, but perhaps it's [one of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=inputattribute+class&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS475US475&oq=inputattribute+class&aqs=chrome.0.57.165&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?)

Comment: It is an attribute. Try to find _InputAttribute_ on Google.

Comment: Click on `Input` in your IDE.  Hit f12 to go to the code definition.  Now you know the namespace, so you can google it with Bing to find relevant documentation.

Comment: @gilly3 Did you really just say "google it with Bing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's an [Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx) -- a way to declare information about your source code. What your particular attribute means depends on the namespace of the attribute. You can hover over it to get information on it or (if the declaration is part of your project) ctrl-click on it to see its source.

Answer (score 0):

Its an attribute.  The full class name is InputAttribute.  Code can reflect over properties and discover attributes, which may modify the behavior or trigger other functionality.  Another example of adding functionality is [Data Annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx), which when used with something that will discover and run them, can be thought of as adding behavior.  You can read more about attributes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (while older, the concept is the same).